# Magento 2: billing address required prior to ordering

Tags: magento2

We offer an assortment only for companies. How do I set the customer to fill in his billing address before placing an order (without billing address impossible place order).

Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

When customer clicks on "Proceed to checkout" button. You have to run an async call to check if the current customer is having default billing address. If not than you have to redirect the customer to a billing address form (you have to create a custom form here). Or better than redirecting you have to open a popup form for billing address. once customer saves saves their billing address, than allow them to access the checkout.

You have to do some customizations.